# How can I use rank function without actually showing rank?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ranking

I am getting:

```
 YEAR   MONTH        DAY SHARES_TRADED NUM_TRADES DOLLAR_VOLUME
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ---------- -------------
      rank
----------
      2010      1          4    1425504460    4628115    3.8495E+10
     1

      2010      1          5    1754011750    5394016    4.3932E+10
     2

      2010      1          6    1655507953    5494460    4.3817E+10
     3
```

But I want to get:

```
YEAR   MONTH        DAY SHARES_TRADED NUM_TRADES DOLLAR_VOLUME
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ---------- -------------


      2010      1          4    1425504460    4628115    3.8495E+10


      2010      1          5    1754011750    5394016    4.3932E+10


      2010      1          6    1655507953    5494460    4.3817E+10
```

I am using rank function like :

```
select year, month, day, shares_traded,num_trades, dollar_volume, rank() over (partition by year, month order by day asc) "rank" from nyse;
```

I want to use rank function but I don't want rank to appear.Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT year,
       month,
       day,
       shares_traded,
       num_trades,
       dollar_volume
FROM   (
  select year,
         month,
         day,
         shares_traded,
         num_trades,
         dollar_volume,
         rank() over (partition by year, month order by day asc) "rank"
  from   nyse
)
WHERE  "rank" = 1; -- Or whatever filtering you want to do on rank.
```

Comment: your solution does not order day ascending .Also it's repeating from month 1 to 12 and over again rather than grouping as all month 1 first then month 2 and 3 and so on.

Comment: @KaliaDona - do you just mean you want to `order by "rank"` rather than filtering with `WHERE "rank" = 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you plan to use the rank() elsewhere, use a CTE

```
with CTE as
(
select year, month, day, shares_traded,num_trades, dollar_volume, rank() over (partition by year, month order by day asc) "rank" from nyse
)
select year, month, day,  shares_traded,num_trades, dollar_volume
from CTE
order by CTE."rank"
```

Comment: invalid identifier

Comment: @KaliaDona - JohnHC has fixed that error, but is there a reason you're using a quoted identifier, which just makes life more complicated and makes that kind of error almost inevitable at some point?